# Weird spacing when using mhchem package

Tags: spacing, mhchem

When I type the following formula in LaTeX

```
$\ce{^{4}He + \gamma \rightarrow {2}p^{+} + 2n}$
```

I get a very weird space between the `2` and `n` in the last term, but there isn't any between the second last term.

But when I added a bracket on the `2` in the last term, the horizontal space disappeared:

```
$\ce{^{4}He + \gamma \rightarrow {2}p^{+} + {2}n}$
```

Is this the proper way to eliminate the space? Or should I just leave it with the original form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`{2}` is an escape mechanism. Simply write `2`.

`\rightarrow` should not be used. Use `->` instead.

You don't need `p^{+}`, `p+` does the trick as well.

So, in summary, write `\ce{^4He + \gamma{} -> 2p+ + 2n}`, this looks how the package author intended. And yes, there is a small space after stoichiometric numbers.

For details, see the [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/mhchem/mhchem.pdf).

As a side note: It is correct to use `\gamma` here, not `$\gamma$`, because it is no variable that stands for a number. However, you should make sure you load a font that includes an upright gamma. Again, see the documentation.